# discord py music bot stops playing

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-api, bots

hi im having a problem with my discord music bot

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx,*,songname):
   
     html = urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={songname}")
     video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
     FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
     YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
     URL =f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_ids[1]}"
     vc = ctx.voice_client

     with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
         info = ydl.extract_info("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_ids[0],download=False)
         url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
         source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
         vc.play(source)
         await ctx.send(f'~(0o0*)~ **playing**:\n{URL}')
```

whenever i play a song after 2 mins
it stops playing and goes cilent

Comment: See if modifying the code to pull audio from another site, preferably from your own webserver if you have one, works. That could help isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related but recently youtube has taken down a lot of music bots so maybe in some new terms of service discord is just not allowing to play music from there.

Comment: Seems unlikely because AFAIK, discord can't see the audio source, because the library handles that. There could be some other method being used to detect it, but I seriously doubt it.